# How to add new element in the array or Clist

Tags: php, arrays, yii, model

I have the following code,

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "questions".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'questions':
 * @property integer $queid
 * @property string $question
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User[] $users
 */
class Questions extends CActiveRecord {

  public $que1 = "";
  public $wh1;
  public $que2 = "";
  public $wh2;
  public $que3 = "";
  public $wh3;
  public $que4 = "";
  public $wh4;
  public $que5 = "";
  public $wh5;
  public $que6 = "";
  public $wh6;
  public $list1 = array('abc', 'fghf', 'hjj');
  public $list2 = array('abc', 'fghf', 'hjj');

  /**
   * @return string the associated database table name
   */
  public function tableName() {
    return 'questions';
  }

  /**
   * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
   */
  public function rules() {

    // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
    array('queid, question, que1,que2,que3,que4,que5,que6, wh1,wh2,wh3,wh4,wh5,wh6', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
    );
  }

  /**
   * @return array relational rules.
   */
  public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'User', 'id'),
    );
  }

  /**
   * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
   */
  public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'queid' => 'Queid',
        'question' => 'Question',
        'que1' => 'Q.1 Which events or actions are expected to be performed ?',
        'que2' => 'Q.2  Which input values or objects to be tested ?',
        'que3' => 'Q.3  Where this action,operation or functionality to be tested ?',
        'que4' => 'Q.4 Who all living or non-living actors/characters performing event/action/operation ?',
        'que5' => 'Q.5  When event/action/operation to be performed ?',
        'que6' => 'Q.6  What are the end results expected from this test?',
    );
  }

  /**
   * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
   * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
   * @param string $className active record class name.
   * @return Questions the static model class
   */
  public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
  }

  public function getlist() {


    if ($this->que1 === "") {

    } else {

      array_push($list1, $this->que1);
      return $list1;
    }
    if ($this->que2 === "") {

    } else {
//               array_push($list2, $this->que2);
//                    
//                return $list2; 
    }
  }

}
```

I used array_push to add new element to array, but its not working, the new element is being overwritten, and I'm always getting a single value, so I tried using array with default values, but same result. I also tried it with Clist and add() function but that too not working. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's that what you are looking for, anyway I post my solution here:

```
$array = array("el1", "el2");
$array[] = "el3";
print_r($array);
```

[Online DEMO](https://eval.in/163696)

Comment: well, I probably typed my answer at almost the same time as @Let me see

Answer (score 0):

`list1` is a class property and so `$this` is important to access it or else it would be considered as local variable to the `getlist()`.

Change -

```
array_push($list1, $this->que1);
return $list1;
```

to

```
array_push($this->list1, $this->que1);  
return $this->list1;
```

Comment: I tried this one, but every time I call model's getlist() function from controller, the new value is getting overwritten...Array ( [0] => abc [1] => fghf [2] => hjj [3] => gfhg ), last index(3) is being overwritten...

Comment: On every request, the array is obvious to have only 2 items in it. In controller you are appending the 3rd item which will be applicable to that request only. Save the array in the session. Then on every request, fetch the array from the session, append the new item and store it in the session again.

Comment: so how can I store the array in session?